# Python Unit test for method contains request

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest, coverage.py

I have a method, which contains external rest-api calls.

ex:

```
def get_dataset():
    url=requests.get("http://api:5001/get_trainingdata")
    filename=url.text[0]
    return filename
```

When I do @patch for this function, I can able to do unittest. But, coverage in not covering whole function.
How can write unittest case for this method with full coverage?

My testcase

```
@mock.patch('api.get_dataset')     
def test_using_decorator1(self, mocked_get_dataset):                  
    file = [{"file":"ddddd"}]         
    mocked_get_dataset.return_value = Mock()
    mocked_get_dataset.return_value.json.return_value = file        
    filename = file[0]
    self.assertEqual(filename, file[0])
```

Comment: I've used [`responses`](https://pypi.org/project/responses/) for this kind of thing.

Comment: How are you patching? What isn't getting covered? Can you rewrite the function to not rely on a hard-coded HTTP request?

Comment: Please don't add code in comments; put it directly in the question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I try to use responses. I have a same issue. 
I can mockup server. But, when I call function in unittest, its calling actual function. And I am getting http request failed.

Comment: [Why Your Mock Doesn't Work](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201908/why_your_mock_doesnt_work.html)

Comment: Where is the code under test? The code use `get_dataset()` function